# Visual Studio 2008. MFC event wizard broken

Tags: visual-studio-2008, events, wizard

OK, so it's almost a programming question -

The VS2008 dialog event wizard has stopped working. Double-clicking on a button in an MFC dialog project does not fire the wizard as usual and a right-click to get to the 'Add Event Handler...' shows a dialog with no message types.

Further to this the MFC message mapping and virtual class listing that generally appears in the properties window (Alt + Enter) is now empty.

Has anyone elese seen this and if so, how'd they fix it? I have 'repaired' my VS08 installation ...

Thx++

Jerry

Comment: For anyone else with this problem:

1. Delete all NCB, PDB, and ILK files in the project folder(s), then retry. This fixed my problem.

2. If you get Javascript error messages after IE8 is installed then check this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/03/28/some-vs2005-and-vs2008-wizards-pop-up-script-error.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> For anyone else with this problem: 1. Delete all NCB, PDB, and ILK files in the project folder(s), then retry. This fixed my problem.

It's the NCB file - delete that and all is well.

Comment: Which version of VS and how does your problem manifest itself?